# MySQL Join through an intermediary table

Tags: mysql

I am building a query and I need to select from the log table multiple columns, my issue is that i'm trying to find a way to select a column that has an FK in a table that has an FK to another table.

I have:

- `log.number_id`,
- `numbers.number_id`
- `numbers.country_id`,
- `countries.country_id`

Query is almost done, my only issue is that I need to show `countries.country_id` through an intermediary table FK `numbers.country_id`, I believe this is an `INNER JOIN` yet I have no idea how to create the concatenation, I searched google for this, yet I couldn't find something like a general formula of how to execute such an intermediary join.

Comment: Post you best attempt so far as well as some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: The syntax for inner join is the same no matter what the tables are called. It's unclear what precisely is stopping from doing this. Can you show how you've tried to write it? Then it might become clearer to us what's puzzling you. But it looks like you will just need two joins instead of one. Maybe that's your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this.
Basically joining the table with both id's to the other tables on the common id.

```
SELECT log.*, ctry.*
FROM numbers AS ctrylog 
JOIN log
  ON log.number_id = ctrylog.number_id
JOIN countries AS ctry
  ON ctry.country_id = ctrylog.country_id
```